# How to extract one column from multiple files and paste them columwise into a new file

Tags: unix, cygwin, paste, cut, file-processing

The input filenames look like this: 1012232U1_000n_1012232U1.TXT with n=1...n and contain five colums separated by diffrerent delimeters

`200,00;  441,080;  353,651;  404,764;212,94154
 201,00;  413,333;  402,073;  422,487;55,48304
 202,00;  449,286;  347,365;  413,185;142,21558
 203,00;  432,591;  387,947;  397,659;88,41888
 204,00;  424,122;  363,040;  401,541;146,12162
 205,00;  441,245;  380,924;  417,946;159,18871
 206,00;  425,077;  350,233;  415,756;124,92821
 207,00;  442,539;  376,096;  418,468;129,83518`

I want to extract the last column of every file and paste them into a new file columwise and not appended. It should look like this:

```
`212,94154;201,61297;...
55,48304;34,53536;...
...;...;...`
```

I tried `$ cut -c39-48 1012232U1_{0001..0096}_1012232U1.TXT | paste -d';' > combinedoutput.txt -` for my 96 files but there appears to be something wrong with the cut input as no matter how I specify paste it always appends all fith colum input in one column in the output file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract all last columns first, so that paste can join them correctly.
Try this:

```
# Extract last columns into temp files.
for f in 1012232U1_{0001..0096}_1012232U1.TXT ; do
    cut -c39-48 "$f" > "$f.tmp"
done
# Join temp files.
paste -d';' 1012232U1_{0001..0096}_1012232U1.TXT.tmp > combinedoutput.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it working now after completely reinstalling cygwin and running dos2unix on all files. It wasn't just the input but also an invisible linebreak character.....